# Linq - isolate lambda as a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Given a Linq sample like this:

```
myObject.firstOrDefault(o => o.propertXyz == otherObj.propertyXyz);
```

How would I extract lambda expression and hold it in a delegate so that it can be passed in?

something like:

```
delegate expression1 = (o => o.propertXyz == otherObj.propertyXyz);
myObject.firstOrDefault(expression1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace 'Object' with the type of object you have.

```
Func<Object, bool> expression1 = (o => o.propertXyz == otherObj.propertyXyz);
myObject.firstOrDefault(expression1);
```

Comment: Alternatively you'd use Action<> if you wanted a void result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the generic [`Func<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) overloads to do this.

For example, if your object is called `myObject`, you would use:

```
Func<myObject, bool> myExpression = o => o.propertXyz == otherObj.propertyXyz
```